# IIS - ASP.NET MVC redirection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, redirect, routes

I have two applications using ASP.NET MVC, each with multiple controllers.

I want to do a redirect from application A to application B, but only for a single route on application A (one controller).

Eg.

/applicationA/issue/* should redirect to /applicationB/issue/

/applicationA/quality/ should not redirect

The examples for IIS redirection are showing me examples of how to click on a file/folder and enable redirection, but I'm trying to do a route, not a physical path.

I don't want to modify the ASP.NET source (if at all possible).

Thanks.

edit - this is in IIS6 on Win2k3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that last bit is a real caveat. If this were on IIS7, it'd be 100% easier!

You could download another app to do the redirecting work, but then it wouldn't be hard to edit the MVC app. Assuming that /issue/ and /quality/ are different routes, why not just do something like this:

```
public class MyController
{
  public RedirectResult Issue()
  {
    //return as a redirect
    return Redirect("http://applicationb/issue");
  }

  public ActionResult Quality()
  {
    //This is here to show that, instead of redirecting, it returns a view.
    return View();
  }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to do it at the IIS level so it was explicit to anyone looking at the management tool.  Looking at UrlRewriting I don't see the benefit of using it over just changing my MVC routes, which seems like the answer.

Comment: Added route to top of list, and then an action that returns a new RedirectResult.  IIS7 seems to address this, but it was just easier in ASP.NET vs. IIS5/6.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [URLRewriting.NET](http://urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html) to do the redirection based on a regex pattern.

Comment: I agree. As solution for IIS6, UrlRewriting.NET is probably the best there is. @Michael, the url that you might want to add to the answer is http://urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html.